# TeamViewer 14 in Virtual Machine

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, teamviewer

When I install teamviewer_amd64.deb in a Debian VM it installs with no error.

I start "teamviewer" and I see this:

```
$ teamviewer

Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...

$
```

So it returns me to the command prompt and I don't see TeamViewer running anywhere like I used to see on TeamViewer 12.

Comment: It's possible that it's still unfinished. Even the Windows version had so many problems that downgrade to 13 was the best solution for now, and the Linux version always comes a bit behind. For example, the fallback to port `443` if other ports are blocked didn't work as before. Also, downloading the `.msi` installation is harder than ever.

Comment: @ms1 TeamViewer 13 also doesn't run in a vm.  That's why I tried TV 14.